# Replay flash (swf) using HTML link

Tags: html, flash

If the page has an SWF banner, and we need to put an HTML link to replay the SWF, we can include the banner in HTML DIV and then make some jQuery to reload the DIV so we can get the SWF from beginning.

Although this is a working way, I was wondering if there is a direct way to replay the SWF from an HTML link without the intrusion of jQuery.

Great Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HTML/Javascript you can call any method (function) in your Flash file using ['ExternalInterface'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

See the [examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: But this is only available when I design the SWF, but for the above case I am hosting banners as ads from many clients.